# Windowssearch.exe and shared folder

Tags: windows-search

I apologize for my poor english.
I would like to launch a search from the cmdline on a remote network drive indexed.
If I manually insert the path,the search is successful.
Something like:
WindowsSearch.exe / url search-ms: query = folder: ("N: \ Invoices \" *) "ceramic"

I've just installed UNCFATPHInstaller.msi, but nothing to do

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you are trying to do, and what does not work ?

Comment: What happens if you don't manually insert the path? Could you give an example of what doesn't work?

Comment: I work with Windows XP. If manually I insert the remote path (it's indexed in remote machine) in windowsSearch from the menu , I meet my search , but I would like to launch this search from the cmdline. With this command: WindowsSearch.exe / url search-ms: query = folder: ("N: \ Invoices \" *) "ceramic" .. I find nothing